# Game of dice in java

Tags: java

The requirements of the program are:
Antonia and David are playing a game.

Each player starts with 100 points.

The game uses standard six-sided dice and is played in rounds. During one round, each player rolls one die. The player with the lower roll loses the number of points shown on the higher die. If both players roll the same number, no points are lost by either player.

Write a program to determine the ﬁnal scores.

I came up with the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class prob3 
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
{
        Random g=new Random();
        int a,b,c;
        int rounds;
        int antonio=100;
        int david=100;

        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the no. of rounds you want to play(1-15):  ");
        rounds=s.nextInt();


        for(int d=1;d<=rounds;d++)
        {
        a=g.nextInt(6)+1;
        b=g.nextInt(6)+1;
        System.out.println("Round "+d+":"+a+" "+b);

        if(a<b)
        antonio=100-b;

        else if(a>b) 
        david=100-a;
        }
        System.out.println("Total for Antonio: "+antonio);
        System.out.println("Total for David: "+david);
        }
        }
```

The program fails to calculate the right sum at the end.
What am I doing wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Where is condition for "*If both players roll the same number, no points are lost by either player*"?

Comment: Please clarify: What do you mean by "...fails to calculate the right sum at the end."?  Generally speaking, questions of this nature that essentially ask all of us to debug your code are discouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing this.

```
 antonio=100-b;
```

When you probably want

```
antonio = antonio - b;
```

The first code simply subtracts the dice roll from `100` every time, which is pointless. You want to subtract the dice roll from the players totals. Do this for both players.

Comment: Or better still `antonio -= b`

Comment: @AndyBrown Wouldn't say better. Shorter though. I prefer the long way.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above the "100 - b" was your main problem. But there is no reason in your problem statement to set a number of rounds.

I whould rather use a loop like this:

```
while(antonio >= 0 && david >= 0){
    //do the same stuff here
}
System.out.println...
```

Since it looks as some exercise for some java course.. This may sound useless but:

- **Format** always your code.. Spaces, brakets and tabs
- Use descriptive variable mames. a b c d are not quite intuitive in a larger program.
- Remover unused variables

Y mucha suerte tío!